# Stroke text with HTML in Java Swing

Tags: java, css, swing

I'm using this string for a Java swing JLabel:

```
"<html>\n" +
"<head><style>\n" +
"p {    color: white;\n" +
"    text-shadow:\n" +
"    -1px -1px 0 #000,\n" +
"    1px -1px 0 #000,\n" +
"    -1px 1px 0 #000,\n" +
"    1px 1px 0 #000; }" +
"</style></head>\n" +
"<body><p>testing123</p></body>\n" +
"</html>"
```

Which is a slightly modified example I found of how to stroke the outline around text with HTML. When I do this, "testing123" shows up in white (or whatever color I place of white), which is good, but no shadow or outline is ever visible, regardless of background. This works on the w3schools css tester page. I read that it only works on certain browsers, so I'm guessing that excludes swing? Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that it only works on certain browsers, so I'm guessing that excludes swing?

You guessed right!  Swing's HTML support includes a **sub-set** of **HTML 3.2**.  The CSS support is equally patchy and incomplete.

> Is there any way to make this work?

The Java-FX based [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) would seem to be the best approach.  Java-FX based components can be embedded into Swing apps.

Comment: Ok, that works! Follow up question... I just want it for the text effects, the rest of it will use `JPanels`, `JButtons` etc, and the text will be 30 or so different labels dispersed throughout, getting removed and replaced on a regular basis. I don't know how its handled internally, would this be significantly more unwieldy then having two or three large `WebView`s?

Comment: I could not say, but I wouldn't worry about efficiency until noticing a problem (e.g. slowdown) of the app. itself.  Even then I'd run a profiler to confirm what it is that is causing the delay - rather then presume any particular part is responsible.